# Why is w3c.dom.Element setting attributes according to the alphabetic order?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmldocument

I am using org.w3c.dom.Element for adding elements to a xml file. Problem here is when setting attributes it adding according to the alphabetic order instead of adding order. How to ignore that behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the order in a resulting serialized form of the XML document, the order of attributes is not significant. From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

Answer (score 4):

As @T.J. Crowder says, the order of attributes in a serialized XML document is not significant.  (And the order of attributes is not part of the XML infoset.)

What this means is that implementations of the DOM, XML parsers and XML serializers are under no obligation to allow to let you specify a particular ordering for attributes in a DOM, or to preserve the apparent ordering when serializing, parsing or transforming an XML document.

If you have some application (or test case) that depends on the order of XML attributes, it is broken and should be fixed.

Comment: Well, I was just writing a piece of codestyle tool that ensures proper order or the attributes (for readability), so "If you have some application (or test case) that depends on the order of XML attributes, it is broken and should be fixed." is not entirely valid

Comment: OK, maybe the application is not broken.  Maybe it is your expectation that you can use a standard / off-the-shelf XML parser that is broken.  Fortunately, many XML implementations are open source, so it should be feasible to *modify* one to behave in a way that you need.